# Counting records issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This probably is a simple one but I cant get my head around it.

I have a table of MemberBusinessCats which contains a BusinessCatID and a MemberID.. the table could be presented like this:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  MemberBusinessCatID  |  BusinessCatID  |  MemberID  |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  27                   |  45             |  102       |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  28                   |  55             |  102       |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  29                   |  61             |  102       |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  30                   |  45             |  33        |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  31                   |  23             |  33        |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  32                   |  45             |  73        |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  32                   |  61             |  73        |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|  32                   |  45             |  73        |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
```

How do I make a script to show the following data

```
+-----------------+---------------------+
|  BusinessCatID  |  NumMembers In Cat  |
+-----------------+---------------------+
|  45             |  3                  |
+-----------------+---------------------+
|  55             |  1                  |
+-----------------+---------------------+
|  61             |  2                  |
+-----------------+---------------------+
|  23             |  1                  |
+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Many thanks in advance.

neojakey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
   select BusinessCatID ,count(BusinessCatID) as NumMembers_In_Cat 
   from MemberBusinessCats 
   group by BusinessCatID
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7dc5/1)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an aggregate function with a `GROUP BY`:

```
select BusinessCatID, count(*) NumMembersInCat
from MemberBusinessCats
group by BusinessCatID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32808/2)

This can also be written using `count() over()`:

```
select distinct BusinessCatID, 
  count(*) over(partition by BusinessCatID) NumMembersInCat
from MemberBusinessCats
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32808/5)

If you want to count the number of members in each category, then you can use:

```
select BusinessCatID, 
  count(distinct MemberID) NumMembersInCat
from MemberBusinessCats
group by BusinessCatID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32808/9)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that you have a combination of BusinessCatID  &  MemberID (45,73) that is listed twice but only counted once you need to do a COUNT(DISTINCT x)

```
SELECT BusinessCatID, COUNT(DISTINCT MemberID) as NumMembersInCat
FROM MemberBusinessCatID
GROUP BY BusinessCatID
```

This will count the distinct members (based on MemberID) per BusinessCatID.  If you aren't worried about the dups then using COUNT(MemberID) or even COUNT(1) will work fine.

Comment: Non of the above answers give desired output as he *exactly* required. He accepted the wrong answer. Everyone is close but you are more closer than anyone. I think it should be `Count(Distinct MemberBusinessCatID)`

Comment: Actually mine does give the correct answer other than order.  Count(Distinct MemberBusinessCatID) gives an identical answer though.  The op didn't really specify which way round he wanted it.  Simple change either way though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (or something like this):

```
       select BusinessCatID ,count(*) as NumMembersInCat 
       from MemberBusinessCats 
       group by BusinessCatID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select BusinessCatID, COUNT(BusinessCatID)
from MemberBusinessCatID
group by BusinessCatID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select BusinessCatID, count(MemberID) as [NumMembers In Cat] 
from MemberBusinessCats 
group by BusinessCatID, MemberID
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the question to be from the distinct TRIPLE (MemberBusinessCATID, BusinessCATID, MemberID), sum over BusinessCATID. In this case looking at distinct triples or doubles is the same, but in a larger data set there may be a difference:

Created a view:

```
create view dist_catView as
SELECT distinct MemberBusinessCATID, BusinessCATID, Member ID from cat_table
```

then

```
SELECT BusinessCATID, count(MemberID) from dist_catView
group by BusinessCATID
```